# Modular Implementation of MongoDB using Promises and Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, async-await

I would like to make an Ajax request to my MongoDB server and use the data along with other async tasks using a standalone function so that I can modularize my code as much as possible. I am not very experienced with async programming so I might be doing some basic mistake. In my code, I used another function (doubleAfter2Seconds) returning a promise, which works fine. The result variable from await getMongoData("mydb", url) is outputted as undefined instead of the actual data.

```html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://{MyServer}:27017/";

function getMongoData(dboArg, urlArg) {
  var myPromise = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      MongoClient.connect(urlArg, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(dboArg);
        dbo.collection(myCollection).find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
          db.close();
          resolve(result[0]);
        });
      })
    })
  }
}

function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("v");
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x * 2);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function addAsync(x) {
  // This works
  const a = await doubleAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(a);

  // This doesn't work
  result = await getMongoData("mydb", url);
  console.log(result);
  return x;

}

addAsync(10).then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but you are not returning anything from your `getMongoData` function.

Comment: What is the `var myPromise = () => {` line supposed to do?

Comment: Don't ever do `if (err) throw err;` inside an asynchronous callback! You should `reject` the promise instead. And probably not forget to close the connection.

Comment: getMongoData() returns as the following: return new Promise(resolve => { ...

Comment: Bergi, you mean like this?         dbo.collection(myCollection).find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
          err 
             ? reject(err) 
             : resolve(data[0]);

Comment: You are storing everything inside `var myPromise = () => {....` but never returning anything outside the function.

Comment: @Bergi, you got me to the right track. Got rid of `var myPromise = () => {` and it now works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected getMongoData function based on the comments

```js
function getMongoData(dboArg, urlArg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    MongoClient.connect(urlArg, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(dboArg);
      dbo.collection(myCollection).find({}).toArray(function(err, data) {
        err 
            ? reject(err) 
            : resolve(data[0]);
      });
    })
  })  
}
```